# Azure Rest api AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader

Tags: azure

I am calling Azure's REST API to get 'List all available virtual machine sizes in a region' from SOAPUI but it gives me error in response..
{"error": {
   "code": "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader",
   "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."
}}
I have set the Authorization header too..

Comment: Can you provide sample of code used?

Comment: actually I have written nothing code for it.. I just picked up one azure api and trying to call using SOAPUI.

Comment: I am going to provision VM in our project so that's why I'm checking or testing it through SOAPUI

Comment: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/vmSizes?api-version={api-version}" - this is the API

Comment: Are you passing in an authentication token in the authorization header?

Comment: Sorry I see that you added the authorization header. Where /  how did you get the token which you have set in the authorization header?

Comment: yes, I have set the token in Authorization header

Comment: I generated it in Azure active directory

Comment: Did you use key directly or did you generate Access Token using the Key?

Comment: I am having this same problem - Have tried Fiddler & Postman and it doesn't seem to recognise the Authorization header that is generated by the Portal. I'm getting really infuriated by this as I've been charged 20 quid so far and I just need to move a storage account!

Answer (score 0):

The api need authentication, so you need to configure SoapUI with client certificate authentication. Your api has no problem. I test your api successfully using powershell.

```
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'
$context = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ("https://login.windows.net/tenantid/")

$cred = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential ("clintid", "key")
$result = $context.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", $cred)

$token = $result.AccessToken

$authHeader = "Bearer $token"
#$authHeader

$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}
$size=Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionsid/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/location/vmSizes?api-version=2015-05-01-preview" -Headers $headers 
$size.value
```